# Basic express setup: not sending anything to local port

Tags: node.js, express

I created a frontend app and now trying to incorporate backend into it.
ON the same frontend app i added an index.js file in the root directory, and installed express and required it in index.js file.

Very basic setup as below:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    greetings: 'hi'
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Server on port ${port}`)})
```

Server is successfully on port 3001 as per my terminal, however, on localhost:3001 I'm not seeing any json response I set up in app.get.
It says Cannot GET / instead. When i inspected in devtool(Network) it says 404.

This seems a very straightforward setup, but what could've gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figured why. I installed nodemon but my “start” script is “node index.js”. Should’ve used “nodemon index.js”
Working now with nodemon index.ks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, There are no errors, I tested it and it works as expected.

However few things to note, Keep Backend in Seperate folder/dirctory unless required.

Coming back to your question, There are many possiblity such as some modules are not installed properly

try running following command

```
//this will install if any library is currupt or not installed properly
npm i
```

if it doesn't work then try [clearing cache](https://coder-coder.com/npm-clear-cache/#:%7E:text=Run%3A%20%E2%80%9Cnpm%20cache%20clean%20%E2%80%93force%E2%80%9D&text=are%20both%20not%20working%20and,npm%20cache%20on%20your%20computer.)

Also keep in mind, In nodeJS dev server does not automatically refresh changes, you need to restart server to see changes or you can use dev dependancy called Nodemon (this will auto restart server on saving changes)

Comment: hey @MilanPatel. thanks for the reply. I discovered what the issue is - I actually installed nodemon but didn't use it in the start script. Actually I switched from "node index.js" to "nodemon index.js" everything's running correctly again.